# Connect external LCD monitor with only 2 Display Ports to Laptop with only HDMI output

Tags: hdmi, external-display, cable, displayport, lcd

I have an LCD monitor with 2 DP inputs only and a laptop having 1 HDMI output. I know it can't directly connect via single cable or HDMI-to-DP converter but via an active adapter.

[image: HDMI to DP converter]

[image: LCD inputs]

I also have type-C port in laptop as well but unable to get C-to-DP cable. But I have a type-C hub docking station having USB-A and HDMI out ports. Can I connect this to my laptop and connect HDMI of HUB to DP of laptop normally using simple converter?

[image: type-c hub]

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that standard HDMI-DP will work, but in this direction it's slim chance (many video sources use [DisplayPort++](https://www.kensington.com/news/docking-connectivity-blog/difference-between-dp-and-dual-mode-display-video-ports/) but it's rare for monitors).

As for USB-C dock - yes it should work with most modern laptops. To be sure, you should check symbol near the USB port: https://www.kensington.com/news/docking-connectivity-blog/usb-c-demystified/ Older and/or budget devices can have "fake" USB-C though (connector is modern, but underlying chip is still old).